# apple swift slideoutMenu indexPath

Tags: ios, swift2

I am creating a slide menu for ios but I'm having problems

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   let DestVC = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController
   let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
   DestVC.varView = indexPath.row
}
```

why doesn't this code work?

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make optional cast cause segue.destinationViewController  is UIViewController that can't be always casted to its subclass

Try this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
guard let DestVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController else { return }
   let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
   DestVC.varView = indexPath.row
}
```

Comment: I always fail in this row

let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

the error is: Value of optional type 'NSIndexPath' not unwrapped; did you mean use '!' or '?' ?

Comment: Didn't notice it first time. you need to retrieve index path like that `let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!` Cause indexPathForSelectedRow isn't a function it is computed property.